# How to execute slack bot from message send through web-hook?

Tags: slack-api

I created a simple Alexa app that **posts a text into a slack channel**.

I defined the message so that it would trigger a slack bot, that is running in the same channel. Like what happens when I type the text manually.

**Example:**
botname *action* *parameter* e.g. herbert ping 192.168.1.1

The message post via web-hook comes in exactly in the same way BUT it does not trigger my bot.

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please provide a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not execute slash commands through incoming webhooks, but you can do it with the undocumented API commands [`chat.command`](http://chat.command). See also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829741/execute-slash-command-as-slack-bot/41164998#41164998).

Answer (score 0):

The command `chat.command` needs the permission scope `post`, which only legacy tokens have and which is not available for Slack apps.

According the the Slack customer support executing slash commands through a web-hook is no longer possible.