# How can I trigger a slash command in Slack every day at a certain time

Tags: slack-api, slack

I want to trigger a slash command in Slack every day at a certain time. Specifically, I want to clear my status every night at midnight.

From the documentation it seems like the only way to do this would be via an [Incoming Webhook](https://api.slack.com/incoming-webhooks). However POSTing with the following JSON body just creates a message in Slack `/status clear` and does not actually run the command.

```
'{"text":"/status clear"}'
```

It also posts the message on behalf of the app associated with the webhook, not under my username.

Is there any way to invoke a slash command for my user from outside the official Slack app?

Comment: How about use of Google Apps Script? Google Apps Script has a trigger. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger Using this, you can use Slack API on the time you want. If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute slash command as slack bot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829741/execute-slash-command-as-slack-bot)

Comment: @Tanaike that provides a way to trigger the post at a certain time, but it does not answer my question about how to invoke a slash command as myself.

Comment: @ErikKalkoken this is not a duplicate as in this case I want to invoke the slash command as myself, not as a Slack bot.

Comment: You can get the same effect for ``/status clear`` by ``{"status_text": "", "status_emoji": ""}`` at ``users.profile.set``. In this case, you can also select the user name. Own status can be cleared by sending this using Google trigger.

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for `users.profile.set` I was looking for that and it can be used with slack application token for whole team :)

Comment: @Marko Kunic I'm glad it could be useful for you. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how to execute slash command for your user with an external script.

1. Use the undocumented API method [`chat.command`](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) execute any slash command, e.g. `/status`
2. Use an access token linked to your user account for the API call. One way to get that is to create a so-called ["legacy token"](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/legacy-tokens) with your user.

Comment: I was stumbling across the exact same problem, so I did a bit of coding and a working example is here:

https://github.com/dazlious/slack-cmd-trigger

You can trigger with your api-token any channel with a command.

Comment: Is there any other way to be able to execute slack commands from a slack app, now that slack's legacy tokens are deprecated.

Comment: Unfortunately, there currently is no way to execute slash commands programmatically. @Avin