# Sending command via Slack API

Tags: post, command, webclient, slack, slack-api

Is there a way to programmatically send a `command` to Slack via the API? I'm successfully posting a message using

```
var postingResponse = client.UploadValues("https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage", 
                      "POST", new NameValueCollection() {
                            {"token","<token>"},
                            {"channel","<ID>"}, 
                            {"text", "/mycommand hello" },
                            {"username","<username>" },
                            {"link_names", "true" },
                            {"parse", "full" }
                       });
```

This works well but the `/mycommand hello` is just printed as text instead of executing as a command. I tried adding a pair `{"command", "/mycommand hello" }` but nothing happened either.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I trigger a slash command in Slack every day at a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43762414/how-can-i-trigger-a-slash-command-in-slack-every-day-at-a-certain-time) and [Execute slash command as slack bot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39829741/execute-slash-command-as-slack-bot)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not try it out by myself, but according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43868371/1364368) there is the undocumented API method [chat.command](https://github.com/ErikKalkoken/slackApiDoc/blob/master/chat.command.md) for executing commands in public channels. There is also a [Python program for sending commands to slack](https://github.com/dazlious/slack-cmd-trigger).

Answer (score 1):

The command `chat.command` needs the permission scope `post`.
However, this scope is now depracted (see [list of all scopes](https://api.slack.com/scopes)).

I just asked the Slack customer support if sending slash commands programmatically is still possible and received the following reply:

> I'm afraid not. Slash commands can only be triggered by human-sent
> messages from the client. Apologies.