# Trigger slack commands programmatically from slack app

Tags: slack, slack-api

I need to create a new slack app which can trigger the execution of slack commands, for example - `/topic NewTopic` needs to be executed by my slack app.

This is kind of a duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40919745/how-do-you-invoke-the-poll-command-using-the-slack-api) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350521/sending-command-via-slack-api), but these got concluded with `chat.command` undocumented method which make use of slack's legacy tokens, and slack warns against the use of legacy tokens.

So I am looking if there is any new way which can accomplish this task of being able to execute slack command programmatically from a slack app.

Comment: The only way currently to do this is to use the `chat.command` method as you had highlighted

Comment: @CalebNjiiri,
I am able to execute slack command as user using the legacy token, how do I execute it as slack app?

Comment: Sorry, but no. There is no other way. Will therefore mark this question as duplicate.