# Schedule a repeating Slack phone call

Tags: slack-api, slack

I would like to schedule a call in Slack to automatically call a set group of people every day at a specified time.  My use case is that I want all members of my team to automatically be called by Slack at 10:45am, for example, every week day for Standup. I don't see any sort of this capability for scheduling calls built-in, but was wondering if anyone else has done this already.

My first thought was using a `/remind` command with just a simple link to a Slack call URL, but it looks like if no one is active in a call, the URL no longer exists.

I figured I'll likely have to build something using the [Slack API](https://api.slack.com/) (if that is even possible) but would love to get ideas from others.

[UPDATE 2019-04-17]

Since this has risen in popularity I thought I'd reach out to official Slack support about this again and received the following response today. It appears this is still not an option (as suspected) but might be in their roadmap. Fingers crossed.

> Unfortunately, we do not currently have a way to programmatically interact with Slack calls so that you can automate your calls. Sorry about that.
>
> I understand how useful this would be though, and I know that there's been recent discussion around building a Calls API and making it open to everyone. I'll let the team know that you'd be keen to see this happen!
>
> We've also talked about ways to create a persistent call link and integrating this into certain calendar apps. There's a lot on our wishlist right now for future additions and improvements.

- Slack Support

Comment: Do you have found some solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no solution. Would still love to have this capability but have not had time to devote to making something. Open for collaboration...

Comment: I tried using the unofficial `chat.command` API call referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39829741/7102718) to make a call but I'm getting a response saying `unknown command`. Guess it doesn't support commands for making calls, though it works for other commands.

Comment: Just use IFTTT to set it up.

Comment: @Flatron IFTTT does not support calling. https://ifttt.com/slack

Comment: From reading the source code of this [unnoficial slack client](https://github.com/raelgc/scudcloud) it seems as though sending a GET request to `<team api url>/call/<channel id>` initiates a call.

Answer (score 15):

As @timotree pointed out in a comment you should be able to initiate a call to a "channel" using: `<team api url>/call/<channel id>`. To automate this, have the call be initiated by a server you own. There you can simply set up a cron job something like `45 10 * * 1-5 <your script> >/dev/null 2>&1` You could use a bash script using a curl request for this, or use the programming language you like.